# store a text string in latex and then add other text to it (concatenate)

Tags: string, latex

I start by defining a command to store the string "Hello":

```
\newcommand{\textstring}{Hello}
```

I would like to append the string " world" but unfortunately this code causes an error:

```
\renewcommand{\textstring}{\textstring world}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `\expandafter`.  For example:

```
% redefine \textstring by appending " world" to it
\expandafter\def\expandafter\textstring\expandafter{\textstring { }world}
```

If you don't use `\expandafter` then you end up with a recursion problem.  You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/expandafter).

Comment: This method works fine (even when the appended text contains commands). 

But now I had another problem with it: when I use \textstring within my text it shows "Hello world" but I have to use it in \endnotetext[\value{enumi}]{\textstring} which generate an empty endnote.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to David Underhill's answer is the following

```
\newcommand{\textstring}{Hello}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\textstring{ world}
\makeatother
```

The `g@addto@macro` macro achieves the same effect, and may produce slightly more readable code (especially if your code is in a package/style, or if you're already in a `\makeatletter` & `\makeatother` situation)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this *overwrites* the definition of `\textstring`, rather than referencing the old one.  In order to append, the standard way is to use the TeX command `\edef`, which expands the definition before assigning something.  Thus, if you have

```
\def\textstring{Hello} % Or with \newcommand
\edef\textstring{\textstring{} world}
```

LaTeX will change the right-hand side of the `\edef` into `Hello world`, and then reassign that to `\textstring`, which is what you want.  Instead, in your current version, the `\newcommand` *doesn't* expand the right-hand side, so when you use `\textstring`, it expands to `\textstring world`, which itself expands to `\textstring world world`, which *itself* expands to… you get the idea.

Comment: This method seems to have problems when the text to add contains commands, it generated many errors.

Answer (score 3):

Used the input from this question to generate

```
\edef\history{ }
\newcommand{\historyAdd}[1]{\edef\history{\history{}#1 }}
\newcommand{\historyAddEcho}[1]{#1\historyAdd{#1}}

The history was: 
\historyAddEcho{Hi brian}
\historyAdd{you idiot}
\historyAddEcho{how are you?}

\lipsum[3]

The real history was: \history
```

(sorry brian, but this was the most illustrative example I could think of)

The scructure can help you create a simple todo list with something like:

```
\lipsum[1]

\historyAdd{\\work more with: }
\section{\historyAddEcho{Introduction}}

\lipsum[1]

\historyAdd{\\work more with the text on page \thepage}
\lipsum[1]

\section{ToDo:}
\history
```

Hope this can help someone out there trying to concat strings for this purpose.