# Is it possible to ask Latex to evaluate a command

Tags: latex, command

This code:

> \begin{enumerate} 
>    \item Item One \def\commandOne{\alph{enumi} : One} 
>    \item Item Two \def\commandTwo{\alph{enumi} : Two} 
>    \item \commandOne, \commandTwo 
>   \end{enumerate}

Gives this output:

> Item One 
>    Item Two 
>    c : One, c : Two

I want that Latex evaluate \alph{enumi} when the command is defined instead of when the command is called, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `\def`, use `\edef` which [expands at the time of definition](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/edef) (see also `\gdef` and `\xdef`).  This can of course cause problems if you want parts of it not expanded.  For those cases you can use `\expandafter` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126082/store-a-text-string-in-latex-and-then-add-other-text-to-it-concatenate).

Comment: Thanks, it works (with \edef). I had tried with \expandafter since the other question was mine also... But it didn't work, I don't really understand how \expandafter works.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the other question was yours.  And yes, \expandafter can be a pain.