# LaTeX not loading - \textstring

Tags: latex, markdown

Goal: re-create this [TPS equation](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Calculation-of-TPS-and-CPS-Schematic-image-of-tumor-specimen-stained-for-PD-L1-Tumor_fig1_343453876) in my Python project's `README.md`.

I want to pass the string, based on this [post's example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3126082/16852041).

---

### Attempts

```
\Huge \frac{{\textstring}{PD-L1 Positive Tumour Cells}}{{\textstring}{Viable Tumour Cells}}\cdot100
```

```
[\Huge \frac{{\textstring}{PD-L1 Positive Tumour Cells}}{{\textstring}{Viable Tumour Cells}}\cdot100\]
```

```
$$\Huge \frac{{\textstring}{PD-L1 Positive Tumour Cells}}{{\textstring}{Viable Tumour Cells}}\cdot100$$
```

```markdown
math :
  <p align="center">
  <img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=\Huge \frac{{\textstring}{PD-L1 Positive Tumour Cells}}{{\textstring}{Viable Tumour Cells}}\cdot100">
  </p>
```

I've also tried `\amsmath`:

```
[\Huge \frac{{\amsmath}{PD-L1 Positive Tumour Cells}}{{\amsmath}{Viable Tumour Cells}}\cdot100\]
```

Nothing loads yet, since I've somehow got it wrong ;(

Comment: Try pasting the URL into a browser: I’m getting an error 404, so the URL is wrong. This has nothing to do with Markdown. However, note that lots of Markdown renderers actually support inline LaTeX equations out of the box so you don’t need to insert pictures.

Comment: Oh might I do so with `\Huge \frac{{\textstring}{PD-L1 Positive Tumour Cells}}{{\textstring}{Viable Tumour Cells}}\cdot100`?

Comment: You will need to consult the documentation of your Markdown renderer. Most support it via the syntax `\[…\]` or `$$…$$`.

Comment: Maybe it is mathjax thing, but `{\textstring}{...}` looks very suspicious...

Comment: Yeah, any time I introduce string it breaks

Comment: Do you confuse this with `\text{...}` from amsmath?

Comment: Isn't working ;(

Comment: The \ in front of `[`  is missing

Comment: There is no such macro as `\amsmath`. As said above use `\text{...}` to insert text and the \ before `[` is still missing. But start with a simple example first in order to find out which syntax your readme uses. Try `\[\frac{1}{2}\]`, `$$\frac{1}{2}$$` or `\begin{equation}\frace{1}{2}\end{equation}`. Does any of them work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [SO Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603559/16852041).

```
<img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?TPS = \frac{\text {PD-L1 Positive Tumour Cells}}{\text {Viable Tumour Cells}}\cdot100" />
```